# Crontab reboot script starts a reboot loop

Tags: linux, sh, cron, raspbian

Okay I'm using Raspbian and have created a Crontab job to reboot every Sunday morning. The issue I'm having is it reboots, but then starts looping. Here's what i did.

Edited /etc/crontab with this.

```
30 3 * * SUN root /home/rpitc/Desktop/Script/Reboot.sh
```

The sh script looks like this.

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The crontab setting works but it continues to run the script. Do i need to alter the sh script to eliminate this loop?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `7` instead of `SUN`. Also you can omit your script, you can simply use the `reboot` command:

```
30 3 * * 7 root reboot
```

Comment: Why do you use `Reboot.sh` at all? Adding the following line to `crontab` should work: `30 3 * * 7 root reboot` .. Is there anything we should know about `Reboot.sh` ?

Comment: I originally used the root reboot within Crontab, but it started looping. I figured that perhaps by bypassing it to a script it would then work. This was not the case though.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Can you test it?

Comment: Okay I just tested it. I set Crontab to run as root and reboot at 10:00. It rebooted, and booted back by 10:00:30 so then it rebooted again (which was expected since it was still 10:00) But then it came back up at 10:01 and continues to reboot every 30 seconds. It is still looping.